# Fowarding a multipart form data with php and cURL

Tags: php, post, curl, proxy, multipartform-data

I'm developing a small proxy in PHP with cURL. It has to receive http requests from a client, make some statistics with this requests, foward the request to the web server and foward the responses to the client. Everything is working fine with GET requests and POST requests with text/html data.

I have problem to foward request with multipart/form-data data, in particular i have data both within the $_POST and $_FILES global variables.

How should I use these two variables to forward the request to the server?

Comment: to send data as `multipart/form-data`, never use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` and `$post` must be an array.

Comment: @virpara - incorrect. Please have a look [here](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2013/07/php-curl-multipart-form-posting.html)

Comment: @pguardiario Actually that post doesn't use `curl`'s own feature for sending `multipart/form-data` It simply passes string in form of `multipart/form-data` and sets header. that is what function `multipart_build_query($f,$b)` does.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store the files in your server first, then use a code like this one :

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $post = array(
        "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: I agree with you, but it's not clear to me hot to proceed.

Usually inside $_FILES I have an array such

   $_FILES  = array (
             uploaded_file: Array(
             name: filename.suffix, 
             type: text/html, 
             tmp_name: C:\client_temp_dir\phpAD3C.tmp, 
             error: 0, 
             size: 100, )
)

Comment: see this link : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php